# How Do I stop the Red and Green Cylinder from moving

Tags: animation

I don't know how to stop the cylinders from MOVING here's a video to show.
https://vimeo.com/282056594

How can I stop the green and red cylinder from moving back and forth?

Answer (score 1):

Tell me if that simple solution could answer:

- Create one unique armature from bottom to top with bones following your object shape.
- Put your armature in *Pose* mode. Select an arm, then select its bone, and *ctrl P* > *Bone* to parent the arm to its bone. For the vertical arms, select the bone it is supposed to be part of and same thing, parent them.
- Move your bones, the arms should follow in the right way.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you did some transforming wrong: the three cylinders should only rotate themselves, but it seems that some of them (red and green) are also translating. Or, you maybe created parenting in a slightly wrong way.

Here below my setup: I placed all meshes, then parented each mesh above to the one below (simple "Object" parent). Then I key framed Z rotation for each cylinder, starting from the bottom, at different frame intervals. Just that.

[image]

And here is how this behave. You could compare to yours or (easiest) start from scratch doing something similar.

[image]